# an asynchronous operation stops the execution of the function code when the jest test is run

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

My test clicks on a button. The event handler requests data from the server and closes the window.
Test code:

```
test('клик по лупе в строке поиска - закроется dropDown', () => {
  const { getByTestId, getByRole } = renderWithProviders(
    <NewDesignTableFilterControl filterView={TableNames.campaigns} />,
  );
    fireEvent.click(getByRole('textbox', { name: /mainsearchinput/i }));
    fireEvent.click(getByRole('button', { name: /search\.svg/i }));
   const elementDropDown = getByTestId('dropDounFilter');
  const classesDropDown = Array.from(elementDropDown.classList);
  console.log(classesDropDown);
  expect(classesDropDown.some((item) => item.includes('hidden'))).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Event handler code:

```
const handlerSearchButton = () => {
    console.log('сработал handlerSearchButton 1'); (1)
    dispatch(setSearchCreator(valueInput));
    saveFiltersDataInStor();
    fetchDataForTable();  // asynchronous operation
    console.log('сработал handlerSearchButton 2'); (2)
    dropDownIsVisible === 'open' && closeDropDownFilter();
    setActiveFilterAndPredFilterData(getCombineData()); 
    console.log('сработал handlerSearchButton 3'); (3)
  };
```

here is the code of the useFetchDataCampaignsForTable hook:

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { useAppDispatch } from 'hooks/redux';
import { fetchDataForCampaignTableThunk, Requester } from '../../../../redux/tableReducer';

function useFetchDataCampaignsForTable(isArchive: boolean | undefined, requester: Requester) {
  const stateFetch = useRef('done');
  const controller = useRef<AbortController | null>(null);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const fetchDataForTable = () => {
    if (stateFetch.current === 'notDone') {
           controller.current && controller.current.abort();
    }
      controller.current = new AbortController();
    stateFetch.current = 'notDone';

    const { signal } = controller.current;

    dispatch(fetchDataForCampaignTableThunk(isArchive, signal, requester)).then((status: string) => {
      if (status === 'Ok') {
        stateFetch.current = 'done';
      }
    });
  };
  return fetchDataForTable;
}
```

The problem is that console.log 2 and 3 are not called when the test is run. If the fetch Data For Table() function call is moved to the end
handler SearchButton then console.log 2 and 3 are called. Can you tell me what this behavior is related to?